# Formal groups in the supersingular reduction case

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, formal-groups

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with potential good supersingular reduction at $p$. Thus, there is a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $E/K$ has good supersingular reduction. Let us choose $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ of minimal degree such that $E/K$ has good reduction, and let us assume $E/K$ is given by a minimal model. Let $A$ be the ring of integers of $K$, let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for $A$, let $\nu$ be a valuation on $K$ with $\nu(\pi)=1$ and $\nu(p)=e$, and let $\hat{E}/A$ be the formal group associated to $E/K$.

Let $[p](X) = pX+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kX^k$ be the formal power series for the multiplication-by-$p$ map on $\hat{E}$. Let $e_0=\nu(a_1)=\nu(p)=e$, and $e_1=\nu(a_p)$. Since $E/K$ is supersingular, we know that $e_2=\nu(a_{p^2})=0$.

If we define points in the plane by $P_0=(1,e)$, $P_1=(p,e_1)$ and $P_2=(p^2,0)$, then $N$, the Newton polygon of $[p](X)$ (for those roots with valuation $>0$) is given either by one single segment $P_0P_2$, or two segments $P_0P_1$ and $P_1P_2$, according to whether $ep/(p+1) \leq e_1$ or $ep/(p+1) > e_1$, respectively.

The number $e$ is a divisor of $12$, and if $p\geq 5$, then $e\leq 6$. If $e>1$, and $N$ has two segments, then $1\leq e_1 < e$. Suppose that we are in this case, i.e., $e_1 < e$.

**Question**: Are there any further constraints on the values of $e_1$?

More specifically:

**Question 1**: Are there any divisibility conditions on $e_1$, or further relations between $e$ and $e_1$? Can $e_1$ take any of the values $1\leq e_1< e$ ?

**Question 2**: Is there a more conceptual way to think about $e_1$?

In all examples I have computed, I get that $e_1=1$, $2$ or $4$ (but I haven't done an exhaustive search either). For instance:

$E=27a4,\quad p=3, \quad [K:\mathbb{Q}]=12, \quad e=12, \quad e_1=2;$

$E=121a2,\quad  p=11, \quad K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{11}), \quad e=6, \quad e_1 = 4;$

$E=14450p2,\quad p=17, \quad K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{17}), \quad e=3, \quad e_1=1.$

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Alvaro

Comment: I am confused about this question. Firstly, you don't seem to make any assumptions on $K$ other than it's a field over which $E$ gets good reduction, so I don't see why $e$ has to divide 12. But more importantly, "the" formal group attached to $E$ depends on a choices of parameter $X$, and there is a huge amount of choice for $X$ as far as I can see, so it's not even clear to me that $e_1$ is well-defined. I think that if $e_1<e$ then it's well-defined, but if it isn't (e.g. if $E$ has good ss reduction over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ then $e_1$ can be pretty much anything.

Comment: For more positive comments -- you could look in Katz' Antwerp paper, where he really uses the power series you talk about and explains some things that really are canonical about it (e.g. he shows that $v(a_p)$ is independent of the choice of $X$ if (1) $X$ satisfies some mild conditions ($[\zeta]X=\zeta X$ for all $\zeta\in\mu_{p-1}$) and (2) $v(a_p)<e$).

Comment: Thank Kevin. I've modified the question so $K$ is chosen to be of minimal degree such that $E/K$ has good reduction. 

Comment: But there is still this more important issue on how one chooses $X$. The formal group is something isomorphic to $R[[X]]$ with $R$ the integers of $K$. But there's no canonical $X$, so there's no canonical $a_p$ etc. For example one can change $X$ to $X'=X+\pi X^2$ and this will completely change $a_p$.

Comment: I see. By "the formal group associated to $E/K$" I was referring to the usual construction (that appears in Silverman, and other sources), where we attach to $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ the formal group $\hat{E}$ with group operation $F(z_1,z_2)=z_1+z_2-a_1z_1z_2-a_2(z_1^2z_2+z_1z_2^2)+\cdots$, and therefore $[p](X)=pX-a_1p(p-1)/2X^2 + \cdots$. Doesn't this choice determine the parameter $X$?

Comment: But there is no canonical Weierstrass equation for $E/K$ right?

Comment: In my mind, "the formal group associated to $E/K$ is just: take the Neron model, and then complete along the identity section, getting a ring isomorphic to $R[[X]]$ (because of smoothness -- but with no canonical isomorphism) equipped with a comultiplication. For me, there is no natural choice of $X$ -- what is canonical is only the ideal $(X)$, which has an awful lot of generators.

Comment: Of course, there is no canonical model for $E/K$, but some of the valuations of the coefficients in $[p](X)$ are invariant regardless of what minimal model of $E/K$ we choose, e.g., the valuation of $a_{p^2}$, i.e., the coefficient in $X^{p^2}$, will be zero, since $E/K$ is supersingular. I believe the valuation of $a_p$ (the coeff in $X^p$) will also be invariant, as long as it is $<e$. The coeffs of $X,\ldots,X^{p-1}$ are $0\bmod p$, so changing $X$ to $X'=X(1+Xf(x))$ will change $a_p$ but not its *valuation* (as long as it is $<e$). 

Comment: I've edited the question so it only asks about the case when $e_1<e$.

Comment: Does the following paper of Coleman help?

http://math.berkeley.edu/~coleman/Canonical/Canonical.pdf

Comment: Felipe, yes it does! It also points to Katz' "p-adic properties of modular forms", where it is shown that $a_p$ is congruent to the Hasse invariant of $E/K$ modulo $pA$, where $A$ is the ring of integers of $K$. This was also mentioned by Serre in passing in "Propriétés galoisiennes...", but I had not been able to find a proof.

Comment: Alvaro: by "Katz' Antwerp paper" in my second comment above I meant this paper of Katz -- apologies -- I thought that this paper was sufficiently well-known that you'd know what I was talking about. I could have been clearer. But maybe you have to be careful -- doesn't Katz put some assumptions on $X$ (for example $[\zeta]X=\zeta X$ for all $\zeta\in\mu_{p-1}$) before he proves anything? Perhaps these can be removed though -- and it shouldn't be hard to check.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, Katz assumes $[\zeta]X=\zeta X$ to prove that $[p](X)$ is precisely of the form $pX + a_pX^p +\cdots$ with $a_p\equiv H(E,w)\bmod pA$, but if you change $X$ to any other generator of $(X)$, say to $X'\in XA[[X]]$, the new coefficient in $X'^p$ will be also congruent to $a_p\equiv H(E,w)$ modulo $pA$.

Comment: And Kevin, yes, I knew what you meant by "Katz' Antwerp paper" in  Modular Functions of One Variable III. As I mentioned, I already knew the congruence with the Hasse invariant from Serre (remark on p. 276 of "Propriétés galoisiennes..."), but not a proof - so thanks for pointing out the reference. This congruence is an answer to my Question 2 above, but I am still trying to figure out whether this provides an answer to Q1 as well.


Comment: If $E$ were just a random curve over a random $K$ with good ss reduction then $e_1$ and $e$ can surely just be anything. Your assumptions imply that the $j$-invariant of the curve is defined over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ though. There are relations between $j$ and $E_{p-1}$, that depend on $p$, and perhaps these give you more restrictions for specific values of $p$. For example $j=E_4^3/\Delta$ and $\Delta$ will be a unit at a curve with pot good redn so this perhaps gives some other restriction when $p=5$. And so on. The question strikes me as rather artificial for some reason. 

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that the reason I am interested in $e_1$ is the following: if the Newton polygon $N$ has two segments, and $\bar{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, then the action of tame inertia on $\bar{k}\otimes E[p]$ is given by the $e_1$-th and $(e-e_1)$-th powers of the fundamental character of level 1 (Serre, "Propriétés galoisiennes...", Remarque in p. 275). 

Comment: I've kept working on this (and also got a few very helpful email message from another MOer) and now I can show that, in the setting of my question, indeed $e_1$ is always $1$, $2$ or $4$. Moreover, there is a formula for $e_1$ in terms of the valuation of $j(E)$. Thanks much to Kevin, Felipe, and the other person who answered by email! 

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Your link is dead, did you mean the paper "[The canonical subgroup of $\{E\}$ is $\{\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbf R}[x]/\left(x^p+\frac p{E_{p−1}(E,ω)}x\right)\}$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ajm/1144070588)"?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes. Thanks for the new link.